local branch differ from all other remote branches
The remote branches had some works ahead of my localBranch i.e., my local branch differs from all other remote branches.
Here's what I did to update my local:

git switch main
git pull
git switch localBranch
Check the files: the files in localBranch are still not updated or different from main branch even if I pulled
While I am on the localBranch, I also did this:
git fetch --all
nothing changed


Everything you're saying is totally expected. The only thing that can change a local branch (such as localBranch), aside from your changing it by editing the working tree (and add-and-commit) is pulling or merging into it. You haven't done any of those things so nothing is changing. Did you have a question about that?

I am assuming a branch name "localBranch" exist on remote.
If yes and you want to get the latest changes of remote to your local repo, then try -
git checkout localBranch
git pull origin localBranch
It will do 2 things.
#1. Get the latest commits from remote "localBranch"
#2. Merge the those commits in your local "localBranch".
You can also get changes from other remote branches to your "localBranch" by command
git pull <remote> <remote-branch-name>

My local branch and its remote branch has nothing in it, I just created and are uptodated. But there are other remote branches which have commits ahead/ and those changes are not reflected in my local branch though I fetch or pull from main

To make those commits available in your localbranch, you need to merge that branch into your local branch.
First checkout to your local branch then run git pull origin <branch_you_want_to_merge>
